# Preview list of selected file before upload (ASP.Net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

Below are coding that i used to display list of files selected.

**Button FileUpload**

```
<asp:fileupload runat="server" id="fileUpload" ClientIDMode="Static" multiple="multiple" onchange="javascript:tblUpload()" />
```

**Table for preview selected file**

```
<table id="tblUpload" border="1">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    tblUpload = function () {
        var input = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
        var output = document.getElementById('tblUpload');

        output.innerHTML = '<tr>';
        output.innerHTML += '<th class="thStyle" style="width: 400px;"><b>File Name</b></th><th class="thStyle" style="width: 255px;"><b>Preview Image</b></th>';
        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
            output.innerHTML += '<td style="padding: 10px; width: 300px;">' + input.files.item(i).name + '</td>' +
                '<td style="padding: 10px; width: 150px; color: #0d47a1"><a href="#">Show</a>&emsp; &emsp; &emsp;<a href="#">Delete</a></td>';
        }
        output.innerHTML += '</tr>';
    }
});
```

What I wanted to do is, only preview list of files selected when button preview is clicked. I am using below code for button preview.

**Button Preview**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPreview" Text="Upload File" />
```

I refer to this site http://www.encodedna.com/javascript/get-the-name-size-count-of-multiple-files-using-javascript.htm and tried to put `onclick="tblUpload()"` at **btnPreview** but it isn't functioning. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only preview when button is clicked you won't want to have `onchange="javascript:tblUpload()"` in the `<input>`.

This jsbin works for me: http://jsbin.com/xaqajogudu/edit?html,js,output

I assume you are using

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPreview" Text="Upload File"
    OnClientClick="tblUpload(); return false" />
```

and not the `OnClick` attribute which is only used in Postback

Comment: I tried this `<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnPreview" Text="Upload File" onclick="FileDetails()"  />` and it throws me an error which is : **FileDetails is not a member of main_aspx**

Comment: Yes, you will get that error. I used `OnClientClick` above, not `OnClick`. `OnClick` is used for executing code in the code behind rather than your javascript.

Comment: I hope the way I wrote that didn't sound rude. I didn't mean it to be :)

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I changed to `OnClientClick` and when clicked the page is refreshing.

Comment: use `OnClientClick="tblUpload(); return false;"` to disable the postback

Comment: You may need to also add `UseSubmitBehavior="False"`

Comment: List of files not showing. Already add the `return false` and `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` but it didn't show anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127246/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-emerald).